# How to alter an Ethernet Packet (a packet that comes from the NIC)? Can I Use Netfilter Hooks?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, netfilter

I want to catch a packet before that packet come up tcp/ip layers and give it to user space with C++ and a UI.

How can I do this? Is Qt & Netfilter something that can do this?

Comment: i want to send packets to user space  when packets receive before cross from datalink layer and alter them, then send altered packets to a specific network card

Answer (score 3):

Qt is helpless there. What you need is to write an netlink NFQueue handler. When your packets are matched by a rule that says -j NFQUEUE, your userspace program will receive those packets, allowing you to accept, drop, or mangle (modify) the packet (only in the mangle table). If you can use GPLv2 libraries, you should use [libnetfilter_queue](http://www.netfilter.org/projects/libnetfilter_queue/index.html) to help you.

Note however, that the mac layer is not complete. This because the networking code need to support various device types, and some non-Ethernet devices do not have MAc addresses. On an Ethernet device, what you get is generally only the MAC address of the sender.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.how can queue packets before prerouting in netfilter hooks to user space and handle queue with NFQueue handler

Answer (score 0):

You may use NFQUEUE and libnetfilter_queue.

```
iptables -t raw -I PREROUTING -p tcp -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 1
```

You can see an example in this site:

[libnetfilter_queue_samplecode](https://code.google.com/p/nattt/wiki/libnetfilter_queue_samplecode)

[Iptables flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvhtZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use something called a Packet Socket.
They are used to send or receive raw packets at Layer 2. So basically the packet will come directly to your program and you can implement your own layer 3 and 4 protocols over it.
Check this official man page for packet socket.

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/packet.7.html